# CodeIgniter SELECT statement wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have this data in my table:

```
 Data 1: 
 - request_type = 'cash'
 - status = 'Confirmed'
 - personnal_fk = 64
 - amount = 100

 Data 2:
 - request_type = 'maintenance'
 - status = 'Pending'
 - personnal_fk = 64
 - amount = 200
```

And here is my CodeIgniter query

```php
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('manage_request');
$where = "(status='Confirmed' OR status='Archived')";
$this->db->where('request_type', 'cash');
$this->db->where($where);
```

What I want is to get only the data where in request_type = 'cash' and status = 'Confirmed' or status = 'Archived' and personnel_fk = 64
but CodeIgniter returns all the data. I run

```php
$this->db->last_query()
```

This is the query statement:

```
SELECT `request_id`, `personnel_fk`, `amount`
FROM `manage_request`
WHERE `personnel_fk` = '64'
AND `request_type` = 'cash'
AND (`status` = 'Confirmed' OR `status` = 'Archived')
```

What would be the problem?

Comment: Sure this is the relevant query? You select from `tbl_name`, the query statement shows `manage_request`. You have request type `cash`, that query statement has `cash_advance`

Comment: put the query statement in mysql, and see the results is true or not

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the `personnel_fk`.

```
$this->db->where('personnel_fk', $personnel_fk);
```

**OR**

```
$this->db->where('personnel_fk', 64);
```